# iOS: UIScrollView not scrolling after UIButton is removed

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, autolayout

I have a view controller that looks like this:

[image]

The root view is a scroll view. When the view first loads, it scrolls just fine.

However, I sometimes need to remove one of the buttons at the bottom with code like this:

```
if (item.url==nil||[item.url isEqualToString:@""]) {
    [overdriveButton removeFromSuperview];
}
```

After doing so, however, the scroll view will no longer scroll. (Those views in the middle of the screen expand, so there's always plenty of content that extends beyond the bottom of the screen).

Note that I am required to use Auto Layout here. My suspicion is that this is part of the problem. Does the removal of the button (and, necessarily, the associated constraints) somehow confuse the scroll view?

Comment: is `item.utl` really an NSString? I've come across cases when runtime exceptions were silently captured by UIKit but made the UI freeze without crashing the app.

Comment: Show us your calculations for the scrollview's contentSize. You might be using your buttons to calculate, which would cause it to stop scrolling

Comment: I'm not setting the content size anywhere. I guess I thought Auto Layout was handling that for me? As I said, it works fine until I remove a button.

Comment: Possibly removeFromSuperView causes internally 'sizeToFit' to be called on the UIScrollView when Auto Layout is on. That would cause the scrollview to expand to the size of its content (bigger than the screen), and then there is nothing to scroll anymore. Set a correct 'contentSize' after removing the button.

Answer (score 0):

Either set UIScrollView's "contentSize" property, or call "sizeToFit" method.